# I can't make div to expand until the bottom of its parent div

Tags: css, html

I want the leftcolumn to expand until the bottom but at the same time to remain above of the footer (I tried `height: 100%` but no luck).

**Here is my markup:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7"/>
 <title>New Project</title> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/global.css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.corner.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/custom.js"></script>
</head>
</head> 
<body id="home">
<div id="header">
 <div class="container">
  <div id="topbar">
   <h1><a href="http://widerdesign.co.nr/">wider design</a></h1>
   <ul id="lang">
    <li><a href="index.php">English</a></li>
    <li><a href="es/index.php">Español</a></li>
    <li><a href="tw/index.php">中文(繁體)</a></li>
    <li><a href="cn/index.php">中文(简体)</a></li>
   </ul>
   <ul id="nav"> 
    <li class="home"><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
    <li class="portfolio"><a href="portfolio.php">portfolio</a></li>
    <li class="about"><a href="about.php">about</a></li>
    <li class="contact"><a href="form.html">contact</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div> 
 </div>
</div>
<div id="content">
 <div class="container">
  <div id="tagline">
   <h2>Maecenas nisl quam, volutpat ut tincidunt quis, rutrum quis nibh. Nulla est nunc, pellentesque ac dictum ac, condimentum convallis odio.</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="mainbar">
   <h2>Left Column</h2>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas quis cursus ipsum. Sed sed justo ac dolor scelerisque commodo id ac nunc. Maecenas quis massa metus, id consectetur sapien. Integer quis nunc porta purus sollicitudin vestibulum eu quis lacus. Vestibulum sollicitudin, turpis a interdum condimentum, lorem nulla consequat purus, a porttitor risus nunc eu felis. Suspendisse mattis justo at nibh aliquet pulvinar. Nulla facilisi. Maecenas nisl quam, volutpat ut tincidunt quis, rutrum quis nibh. Nulla est nunc, pellentesque ac dictum ac, condimentum convallis odio. Quisque vitae mauris quam. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam sit amet ante lectus, sed placerat augue. Proin quis convallis felis. Sed nec urna id nulla ultricies varius non et leo. Vivamus mollis porttitor metus sit amet faucibus. Vestibulum placerat ante in est egestas viverra. Fusce elementum ante eu libero condimentum eget sagittis felis gravida. Nunc ac orci vel urna tempus sodales.</p>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas quis cursus ipsum. Sed sed justo ac dolor scelerisque commodo id ac nunc. Maecenas quis massa metus, id consectetur sapien. Integer quis nunc porta purus sollicitudin vestibulum eu quis lacus. Vestibulum sollicitudin, turpis a interdum condimentum, lorem nulla consequat purus, a porttitor risus nunc eu felis. Suspendisse mattis justo at nibh aliquet pulvinar. Nulla facilisi. Maecenas nisl quam, volutpat ut tincidunt quis, rutrum quis nibh. Nulla est nunc, pellentesque ac dictum ac, condimentum convallis odio. Quisque vitae mauris quam. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam sit amet ante lectus, sed placerat augue. Proin quis convallis felis. Sed nec urna id nulla ultricies varius non et leo. Vivamus mollis porttitor metus sit amet faucibus. Vestibulum placerat ante in est egestas viverra. Fusce elementum ante eu libero condimentum eget sagittis felis gravida. Nunc ac orci vel urna tempus sodales.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="sidebar">
   <h2>Right Column</h2>
   <p>Pellentesque faucibus est eu tellus varius in suscipit augue dapibus. In turpis ligula, faucibus eu mollis non, tincidunt ac magna. Integer tempor laoreet lacus, non accumsan ligula eleifend a. Nulla vitae tortor mauris. Fusce dapibus ultrices nibh id dignissim. Phasellus eget nibh ac quam rutrum mollis at vitae nisl. Morbi ultricies tristique tortor sed elementum. Vivamus id neque et lectus commodo tempor. Integer tincidunt, nunc ac hendrerit vestibulum, orci nisl commodo odio, a tempus leo libero nec sapien. Praesent a urna non diam mollis tristique. Duis nec elit lorem, vitae tristique nisi. Proin vel nulla in lectus consequat luctus ut et velit.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
 <div class="container">
  <div id="bottombar">
   <p>Copyright © 2009 New Project. All Rights Reserved. </p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</body> 
</html>
```

**Here is my CSS:**

```
/* reset */
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 outline: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 vertical-align: baseline;
 background: transparent;
}
body { line-height: 1; }
ol, ul { list-style: none; }
blockquote, q { quotes: none; }
blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
:focus { outline: 0; } /* remember to define focus styles! */
ins { text-decoration: none; } /* remember to highlight inserts somehow! */
del { text-decoration: line-through; } /* tables still need 'cellspacing="0"' in the markup */
table { 
 border-collapse: collapse; 
 border-spacing: 0; 
}
/* tags */
body {
 background: url(../images/bg.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0 #F9F9F9;
 color: #666;
 font-family: Arial, "MS Trebuchet", sans-serif;
 font-size: 75%;
}
h1 { 
 font-size: 24px;
}
h2 {
 color: #69C;
 font-size: 16px;
 margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}
p {
 line-height: 160%;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
a {
 color: #69C;
 list-style: none;
 text-decoration: none;
}
/* classes */
.container {
 margin: 0 auto;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 960px;
}
/* structure */
#header {
 /* background: #EEE */
}
#topbar {
 background-color: #F9F9F9;
 float: left;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 margin: 0 20px;
 width: 880px; /* 720 */
}
#topbar h1 {
 background: url(../images/logo.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0 #F0F0F0;
 display: inline; /* ie6 hack */
 float: left;
 padding: 0 0 0 40px;
 text-indent: -9999px;
 width: 164px;
}
#header a { 
 color: #999;
}
#nav {
 clear: both;
 float: left;
 padding: 20px 0 0 0; 
}
#nav li {
 float: left;
 margin: 0 30px 0 0;
}
#nav li a {
 float: left;
 font-size: 16px;
 outline: none;
 text-decoration: none;
}
#nav li a:hover {
 color: #666;
}
#lang {
 float: right;
 padding: 9px 0 0 0;
}
#lang li {
 float: left;
 margin: 0 0 0 20px;
}
#lang li a { 
 font-size: 10px;
}
#home li.home a, #portfolio li.portfolio a{
 color: #666;
}
#content {
 /* background: #EEE */
}
#tagline {
 background-color: #F9F9F9;
 float: left;
 font-size: 20px;
 padding: 20px 20px;
 margin: 0 20px;
 width: 880px;
}
#tagline h2 {
 font-size: 24px;
 font-weight: 700;
 color: #999;
}
#sidebar {
 background-color: #F9F9F9;
 float: right;
 margin: 0 20px 10px 0;
 padding: 20px;
 width: 170px;  /* 240px */
}
#mainbar {
 background-color: #F9F9F9;
 float: left;
 padding: 20px;
 margin: 0 0 0 20px;
 width: 670px; /* 720 */
}
#footer {
 background: #333;
 color: #EEE;
 height: 100px;
}
#bottombar {
 clear: both;
 padding: 15px;
}
```

**Live page:**

http://weedcl.zxq.net/

**EDIT: I tried this:**

```
html, body, #content div.container, #mainbar {
    height: 100%
}
```

But still not working

Comment: You need to put it on #content as well, not just the .container

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm no CSS guru, but if I remember correctly it's because the height property is in relation to the elements parent element. In that case it means you have to set the size of the parent element as well, either with an actual value or with a percentage, if you do set a percentage that has to be in relation to it's parent too.

So in your example as far as I can see you have `html > body > #content > #mainbar` all of which needs the `height: 100%;`

I hope it fixes it.

Edit:

[I found this link that might help you too](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page)

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to do this, if both columns are going to be white, is to change the container HTML like so:

```
<div class="container" style="background-color: #ffffff;">
  <div id="tagline">
   <h2>Maecenas nisl quam, volutpat ut tincidunt quis, rutrum quis nibh. Nulla est nunc, pellentesque ac dictum ac, condimentum convallis odio.</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="mainbar">
   <h2>Left Column</h2>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas quis cursus ipsum. Sed sed justo ac dolor scelerisque commodo id ac nunc. Maecenas quis massa metus, id consectetur sapien. Integer quis nunc porta purus sollicitudin vestibulum eu quis lacus. Vestibulum sollicitudin, turpis a interdum condimentum, lorem nulla consequat purus, a porttitor risus nunc eu felis. Suspendisse mattis justo at nibh aliquet pulvinar. Nulla facilisi. Maecenas nisl quam, volutpat ut tincidunt quis, rutrum quis nibh. Nulla est nunc, pellentesque ac dictum ac, condimentum convallis odio. Quisque vitae mauris quam. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam sit amet ante lectus, sed placerat augue. Proin quis convallis felis. Sed nec urna id nulla ultricies varius non et leo. Vivamus mollis porttitor metus sit amet faucibus. Vestibulum placerat ante in est egestas viverra. Fusce elementum ante eu libero condimentum eget sagittis felis gravida. Nunc ac orci vel urna tempus sodales.</p>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas quis cursus ipsum. Sed sed justo ac dolor scelerisque commodo id ac nunc. Maecenas quis massa metus, id consectetur sapien. Integer quis nunc porta purus sollicitudin vestibulum eu quis lacus. Vestibulum sollicitudin, turpis a interdum condimentum, lorem nulla consequat purus, a porttitor risus nunc eu felis. Suspendisse mattis justo at nibh aliquet pulvinar. Nulla facilisi. Maecenas nisl quam, volutpat ut tincidunt quis, rutrum quis nibh. Nulla est nunc, pellentesque ac dictum ac, condimentum convallis odio. Quisque vitae mauris quam. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam sit amet ante lectus, sed placerat augue. Proin quis convallis felis. Sed nec urna id nulla ultricies varius non et leo. Vivamus mollis porttitor metus sit amet faucibus. Vestibulum placerat ante in est egestas viverra. Fusce elementum ante eu libero condimentum eget sagittis felis gravida. Nunc ac orci vel urna tempus sodales.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="sidebar">
   <h2>Right Column</h2>
   <p>Pellentesque faucibus est eu tellus varius in suscipit augue dapibus. In turpis ligula, faucibus eu mollis non, tincidunt ac magna. Integer tempor laoreet lacus, non accumsan ligula eleifend a. Nulla vitae tortor mauris. Fusce dapibus ultrices nibh id dignissim. Phasellus eget nibh ac quam rutrum mollis at vitae nisl. Morbi ultricies tristique tortor sed elementum. Vivamus id neque et lectus commodo tempor. Integer tincidunt, nunc ac hendrerit vestibulum, orci nisl commodo odio, a tempus leo libero nec sapien. Praesent a urna non diam mollis tristique. Duis nec elit lorem, vitae tristique nisi. Proin vel nulla in lectus consequat luctus ut et velit.</p>
  </div>
  <div style="clear: both; overflow: hidden; height: 1px;"></div>
 </div>
```

I've added styles inline for speed but obviously you can move them into the stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply add that *background-color: #F9F9F9;* directly to the container div!?

like so:

```
#content .container {
    background: #F9F9F9
}
```

This will solve the problem